# Intended selection bias

Tags: stochastic-processes, bias, graphical-model, graph-theory, selection-bias

[Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias) or [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias) is often presented as something that has to be overcome, **avoided**, or at least appropriately considered because it's a problem otherwise. I wonder how often situations arise (for statisticians) that some biased sampling is on the contrary **required** (to get desired results).

I find myself in the situation that I have - abstractly speaking - a bag of balls of two equally distributed colors. If I pick a ball uniformly at random it is a red or a blue ball with equal probability $p_{\textsf{red}} = p_{\textsf{blue}} = 1/2$. But then I want to get a red ball with probability $p_{\textsf{red}} = 2/3$ – for whatever reasons. And I wonder how this is best achieved.

Two methods come to my mind:

1. Create another bag with two copies of each red ball in the
   original set and one copy of each blue ball. Now the probability of
   picking a red ball uniformly at random is $p_{\textsf{red}} = 2/3$.<sup>(1)</sup>
2. Pick a ball uniformly at random from the original set. If it is a red one (which happens with probability $1/2$), keep it. If it is a blue one, create a random number $r$. If $r > \theta$, put it back and pick another ball uniformly at random. Keep it.

How has $\theta$ to be chosen to end up with a red ball with probability $2/3$? Assume $\theta = 0$, i.e. when you pick a blue ball you always put it back and pick another ball. With probability $1/2$ it is a blue ball again, and you end up with this. So the probability that you end up with a red ball is $p_{\textsf{red}} = 1/2 + 1/2\cdot 1/2 = 3/4$?<sup>(2)</sup> To achieve $p_{\textsf{red}} = 2/3$ you have to choose $\theta$ such that $1/2 + 1/2\cdot (1-\theta)\cdot 1/2 = 2/3$, i.e. $\theta = 1/3$.

My questions are:

> - Is this procedure sound?
> - Are there possible pitfalls?
> - Is it possibly a common procedure to efficiently perform biased sampling?
> - How is it named?

Finally: What are typical situations - from the point of view of a statistician or "[stochastician](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/567344/10616)" - where one needs this kind of biased sampling? Some specific (or abstract) use cases would be welcome!

---

**Background:** My specific use case is from stochastic network generation:

When applying the standard [configuration model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model) to generate graphs with a given degree sequence, the resulting graphs have almost no clustering (i.e. a very small mean [clustering coeffient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient)). To avoid this and to generate graphs with a given mean clustering coefficient, you have to choose pairs of stubs to be connected not uniformly at random, but have to favour those which result in triangles ([triadic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triadic_closure)). So having picked one stub, among those to choose next the ones with distance 3 from the first one are to be chosen with higher probability. (This approach could be an alternative to [M.J.E. Newman's generalization of the standard configuration model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4009.pdf) with prescribed triangle distribution.)

It may be not by chance that my use case is from the context of **stochastic synthesis** and not from **statistical analysis** where biased sampling always is to be avoided. But I may be wrong.

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> If you want to pick several samples without replacement, then after picking a red copy you have to remove the other copy, too.</sup>

<sup><sup>(2)</sup> If you want a higher probability than $3/4$ of getting a red ball, you have to put back blue balls at least a second time. If you want to get a red ball with probability $1$ (as long as there **is** a red ball), you  have to put back blue balls until you get a red one, which eventually will happen. This is equivalent to **searching** for red balls and pick them.</sup>

Comment: Research the Radon-Nikodym Theorem and information about "change of measure."  The [Girsanov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem) could be a good place to begin.

Comment: @whuber: There seems to be a long way from my simple question to the rather sophisticated concept of "change of measurw

Comment: ... measure". Can you help me to make the first steps from the one to the other?

Comment: You appear to want to change the probabilities in a stochastic process: that's what "change of measure" means.

Comment: @whuber: My question is: why do others need and perform a "change of measure"? When is it  justified? What shall be achieved by it? I can answer these questions for my own use case, but what are other use cases?

Comment: This is explained in the link I provided earlier: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem#Application_to_finance.  One of the earliest applications, the Black-Scholes formula, earned a Nobel prize.

Comment: @whuber: There is nothing between my naive question and the Nobel prize?

Comment: A little research into the financial applications would be a good start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124493/discussion-between-hans-peter-stricker-and-whuber).